# filtering a .csv file by feature with Pandas and dictonaries

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to separate a given .csv file by a certain feature.
Per request the `load_data` function can't be changed.

Is there a better way to filter the valid data (the entire row of the given .csv file) into data_valid and the invalid data to data_invalid?

```
def load_data(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    data = df.to_dict(orient='list')

    return data
```

```
def filter_by_feature(data,feature):
    data_valid=[]
    data_invalid=[]

    i=0

    for k in data[feature]:
        if k == 1:
            append_line_to_dict(data_valid,i)
        else:
            append_line_to_dict(data_invalid,i)
        i+=1
```

the `append_line_to_dict` function simply iterates over all the dictionaries with the index it receives and appends them.

for example given this .csv

```
ind name is_legal
0   James 1
1   Dykan 0
2   Sam   1
3   Jake  1
```

data looks like

```
data = {['ind':[0,1,2,3],'name':["James","Dylan","Sam","Jake"],'is_legal':[1,0,1,1]
```

data_valid should look like

```
data_valid = {['ind':[0,2,3],'name':["James","Sam","Jake"],'is_legal':[1,1,1] ]}
```

This is my code

```
data = load_data(path)
filter_by_feature(data,"is_legal")
```

Comment: Please share the complete example of the data. It's not clear on what basis you wanna filter. and what's the value of a feature that you're passing in a function?

Comment: @Nk03 Hope the edit I made helps

Comment: @Aame How are you trying to call your function? In the example you've mentioned, what are the "features" you are using as an argument to your functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in this way-

```
data = {
    "ind": [0, 1, 2, 3],
    "name": ["James", "Dylan", "Sam", "Jake"],
    "is_legal": [1, 0, 1, 1]
}
def filter_by_feature(data,feature):
    data_valid={}
    data_invalid={}

    # print(data['is_legal'])
    valid_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(data[feature]) if x == 1]
    invalid_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(data[feature]) if x != 1]
    for key,item in data.items():
        valid_item = [item[i] for i in valid_indices]
        invalid_item = [item[i] for i in invalid_indices]
        data_valid[key] = valid_item
        data_invalid[key] = invalid_item
    
    print(data_valid)
    print(data_invalid)
            
filter_by_feature(data, 'is_legal')
```

**output-**

```
{'ind': [0, 2, 3], 'name': ['James', 'Sam', 'Jake'], 'is_legal': [1, 1, 1]}
{'ind': [1], 'name': ['Dylan'], 'is_legal': [0]}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I am trying to refrain from using Panda's DataFrame (not by choice)...

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer. Is this what you need ?. If yes, then I'll edit and explain it.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it!